# How to recreate a deleted .idea?

Tags: pycharm

I deleted `.idea` on Pycharm, how can I regenerate it?

I tried looking for project structure but can't find it.

I searched in Google "how to regenerate .idea" and found no explanation.

How can I do it on Mac, and how can I do it on Windows?

Comment: The first result on my Google search *"how to regenerate .idea pycharm"* was [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000799230-lost-my-idea-folder)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-opening the directory/folder from within PyCharm will create a new `.idea` directory structure.

PyCharm Documentation:

[Open, reopen, and close projects](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/open-projects.html)

Comment: what do you mean by within Pycharm ?

Comment: can you tell me what to press ?